# ¿Por qué no obtengo todas las filas que estoy esperando?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT t.SI_Articulo,
       m.SI_Descripcion,
       t.SI_UM,
       c.SI_OV, 
       t.SI_Ubicacion 
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m 
      ON m.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo
INNER JOIN SI_Conteo c 
      ON c.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo
```

La cual me debe de traer todo los campos seleccionados, pero pasa que si no tiene `c.SI_OV` no me los trae, es decir, por ejemplo si un articulo no tiene ov no me lo muestra y solo me estra mostrando los que tienen ov.

pero si le quito este INNER JOIN `INNER JOIN SI_Conteo c ON c.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo` si me muestra todo.

y lo otro es que si tiene ov como hago para reemplazarlo por un `*`.

Comment: Reemplaza el `INNER JOIN` por un `LEFT JOIN`, si tienes dudas de las diferencias armamos una respuesta

Comment: Y para reemplazar el numero que trae `c.SI_OV` por un  `*` ? se hace un replace ?

Comment: No entiendo del todo tu pregunta, pero tal vez la respuesta sea esta: `(CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END)`

Comment: Asi es. en que parte va la condicion CASE?

Comment: Todo el CASE reemplaza al campo c.SI_OV en el SELECT

Comment: Muchas gracias,  si desea arma la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Un poco tarde, pero vamos a dejar una respuesta a tu pregunta:

```
SELECT t.SI_Articulo,
       m.SI_Descripcion,
       t.SI_UM,
       (CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END),
       t.SI_Ubicacion 
       FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t
       LEFT JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m 
            ON m.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo
       LEFT JOIN SI_Conteo c 
            ON c.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo
```

Para que te traiga todas las filas de `SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD` aunque no haya coincidencia con `SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD` deberías usar un `LEFT JOIN`. Por último si quieres indicar con `*` la existencia de `c.SI_OV` puedes hacer `(CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END)`.